# How to use an MR16 bulb in a 5"/6" can housing

Tags: lighting, recessed-lighting

I want to hang a nice metallic photograph print over my fireplace. I currently have a 5" recessed can with a fish eye for a PAR30 bulb, but I don't like the evenness of color or the width of the spot from the PAR30. So I'd like to try to convert the can to use a MR16 bulb.

Is there a trim kit that allows you to install a MR16 bulb in a conventional 5" or 6" can, without having to replace the housing? I've looked at the major online retailers as well as some manufacturer's websites (i.e. Halo) but have come up empty. The ones I have been able to find all require a low voltage housing.

Answer (score 1):

These are pretty common for 6" lights. I don't think I've ever seen a 5" retro kit for art lighting.

They're called retro kits.

[6" Retro Slotted Trim](http://www.totalrecessedlighting.com/6-inch-recessed-mr16-retrofit-white-slot-trim.html)

[image: img 1]

[Retro Transformer](http://www.build.com/elco-etrk50-track-lighting/s502136?uid=1662824&gclid=CjwKEAiAi4a2BRCu_eXo3O_k3hUSJABmN9N1V0peawUOPxdaSIzWWQq5s3DXxOJykFLd-9EFfbELuRoCOTLw_wcB&source=gg-gba-pla_1662824____89169149719&s_kwcid=AL!4215!3!89169149719!!!g!138506076554!&ef_id=VeZk0wAAAMNWjklQ%3A20160216035359%3As)

[image: img 2]